# Should I get a router with ipv6 support?

Tags: router, performance, ipv6, gigabit-ethernet, ipv4

I'm in the process of getting a new gigabit router so I can transfer files faster to and from my Lacie Network Space. I found Asus RT-N56U Wireless N Dual Band Gigabit Router. [Its performance is really good, **however it doesnt support ipv6**.](http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/index.php?option=com_chart&Itemid=189)

On the other hand, the world is running out of ipv4 addresses and we've already implemented ipv6. **So I'm wondering whether it's better to get a router with ipv6 support, to be future proof.**

Comment: Shopping questions are off topic as per the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq).

Comment: I think this is a legitimate question, regarding whether IPv6 should be a factor in choosing a router, and so not really asking for a specific shopping recommendation.

Comment: My main concern is whether i should get a router with ipv6 support as the topic. I editted the content of the question so it focuses more on ipv6 issue. Is there anyway that i can reopen this question?

Comment: You're still asking if you should buy a certain router dependent on price

Comment: Note that c|net now has the Asus RT-N56U router listed as one of the [Top 5 IPV6 Ready Wireless Routers](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-3132_7-57447988-98/top-5-ipv6-ready-wireless-routers/)

I assume this is because there is now a beta firmware in the wild which is reported to have working IPV6 support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your ISP provide you with a static IP address?

If so then you don't need to have a router that supports IPv6 *at the moment*. That IP address is "yours" for the time being.

If you have a dynamic IP address then you still might be OK. Your ISP allocates addresses from a block of IPv4 addresses, so as long as they can carry on with their current allocation you'll get an IPv4 address.

At some point your ISP is going to start allocating IPv6 addresses. At that point you'll need a router that will handle them. However, they should give you fair warning that this is going to happen. It would probably be worth waiting until then as price/performance ratio should be better in the future.

Comment: I use Shaw in Canada and they give me dynamic ip address. I'm wondering when they are going to allocate ipv6 addresses, probably in 2 years?

Comment: @hngo - you'll have to ask them. They'll have a pool of addresses and there's a good chance you get the same one most of the time anyway. It'll be when that pool runs out.

Answer (score 0):

Note that IPV6 is not only for what address your ISP can allocate you, but also if you can visit others (sites, hosts, P2P etc) who already have IPV6 address. So if you want to visit a site which has IPV6 address (e.g. http://ipv6.google.com/) unless your router, ISP support IPV6 DNS resolution you won't be able to access it. You can use http://test-ipv6.com/ to check if your current ISP and Router support it or not.